# Convert date range to month range with divided amount [doesn't what procedure]

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

Table data is given below, need to convert it in output format

Table Data

```
Start_date  End_date    amount
14apr2020  13may2020   200
15May2020  16June2020  320
```

Output Need

```
Start_date  End_date    amount
14apr2020  30Apr2020   100
1may2020   13may2020   100
15May2020  31May2020   160
1June2020  16June2020  160
```

Comment: Mysql also works for me, but not procedure @Akina

Comment: Do you really store dates in this format?

Comment: No, its a sample only. You can give a solution using any date format

Answer (score 1):

> Mysql also works for me

### The solution for MySQL 8+.

Look at the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9abfe4e481874c6276bdba7c29d9156) - it shows in detail how to get the desired result.

The query itself:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
-- obtain first day of the least and greatest month/year in a table
cte1 AS ( SELECT LAST_DAY(MIN(Start_date)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH firstday,
                 LAST_DAY(MAX(End_date)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH lastday          
          FROM test ),
-- generate first and last day list for each month/year within the range obtained in cte1
cte2 AS ( SELECT firstday, LAST_DAY(firstday) lastday 
          FROM cte1
        UNION ALL
          SELECT firstday + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, LAST_DAY(firstday + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          FROM cte2
          WHERE firstday < ( SELECT lastday
                                FROM cte1 ) )
-- now obtain desired information
SELECT *, 
       GREATEST(test.Start_date, cte2.firstday) startday,
       LEAST(test.End_date, cte2.lastday) endday,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,
                     LAST_DAY(test.Start_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
                     LAST_DAY(test.End_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + 1 months,
       test.amount / (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,
                                    LAST_DAY(test.Start_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
                                    LAST_DAY(test.End_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + 1) amount_per_month
FROM test
-- joining tables by ranges overlapping
JOIN cte2 ON test.Start_date <= cte2.lastday
         AND cte2.firstday <= test.End_date
ORDER BY id, Start_date
```

Excess output columns are not eliminated for studying purposes. Investigate.

Comment: Great accepted this as this was working, but wanting answer without Recursive

Comment: @AshishMohan *wanting answer without Recursive* Replace recursive CTE with static dates list generator (for MySQL). Or use UDTF (for HiveQL).